# Upload file using JS and REST. Specify content type

Tags: content-type, rest, file-upload, client-object-model, file

I can upload file to SharePoint library using JS and REST.
The content type of added file is as library default content type.
How can i specify file content type when uploading file? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify metadata when uploading a file via REST.  You have to upload the file, then update it afterwards.  To specify content type, simply specify the ContentTypeId when updating the metadata.